# roughike bottom bar, вопрос по библиотеке

Tags: android, android-fragment

Ковыряя [данную](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) библиотеку, встал очередной вопрос.

Как сделать переход между фрагментами по выбору вкладки(как в `TabLayout`)? Нашел метод `bottombar.setFragmentItems();`, но не могу понять как с ним работать. Подскажите способ решения проблемы. Или использовать `ViewPager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, работы с фрагментами, как таковой, здесь не предусмотрено (если неправильно понял, извините, бегло глянул). Но есть все инструменты для этого:

1 Создаете фрагменты, которые Вам необходимы

2 Добавляете первый фрагмент в контейнер

3 В `OnTabClickListener` обрабатываете смену фрагментов:

```
mBottomBar.setOnTabClickListener(new OnTabClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(int position) {
        //тут смена фрагментов. Как-то так:
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                MyFragmentOne fragmentOne = new MyFragmentOne();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                break;
            case 1:
                MyFragmentTwo fragmentTwo = new MyFragmentTwo();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentTwo);
                break;
            default:
                MyFragmentThree fragmentThree = new MyFragmentThree();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentThree);
            break;
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReSelected(int position) {
        // The user reselected a tab at the specified position!
    }
});
```

4 Делаете под себя.

Comment: Спасибо, но возникла еще одна проблема, не знаю можно ли писать тут или надо создавать отдельный вопрос. В общем пишет `Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment` не могли бы вы подсказать как оформить XML файл, я сделал `RelativeLayout` в нем `fragment` и задал ему в `tool:layout` layout фрагмента 1, и меняю как вы показали выше. А при использовании `FrameLayout` просто не отображаются, без каких либо ошибок.

Comment: Все, разобрался, большое спасибо за развернутый ответ.